# How to grep on Sbt output?

Tags: bash, scala, sbt

I want to run `grep` on sbt output, but can't find a way to do it.

Say, if I run Sbt command `./sbt dependency-tree`, it will output:

```
[info] Resolving org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.4 ...
[info] Resolving org.slf4j#slf4j-api;1.7.5 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-lang#scala-compiler;2.10.4 ...
[info]   | +-org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.6.4
[info]   +-org.apache.commons:commons-dbcp2:2.0
[info]   | +-org.apache.commons:commons-pool2:2.2
[info]     +-org.scalaz:scalaz-core_2.10:7.0.6 [S]
[info]   +-org.scalaz:scalaz-core_2.10:7.0.6 [S]
[info]   | +-org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.6 (evicted by: 1.7.7)
[info]   | +-org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.7
[info]   +-org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:1.7.7
...
```

I want to run `grep org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:1.7.7` to filter if this library is used in this project.

But I tried: `./sbt dependency-tree | grep org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:1.7.7`, which is not work and reports some errors from sbt.

I can save the output to a file, then grep on the file, like:

```
 ./sbt dependency-tree > a.txt
 cat a.txt | grep org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:1.7.7
```

Which works but not convenient.

Is there any better command to do it?

Comment: Sorry, `./sbt dependency-tree | grep org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:1.7.7` is actually working. It was wrong because some other mistakes

Answer (score 1):

1. You should quote grep pattern
2. You should use fixed string search

Try this command:

```
./sbt dependency-tree | grep -F 'org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:1.7.7'
```

Comment: Sorry, just found `./sbt dependency-tree | grep org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:1.7.7` is actually working. It was wrong because some other mistakes

Comment: That's good but `grep org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:1.7.7` is still error-prone as it will also match `org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:15797` as dot matches anything